# ISAPI Rewrite Rule

Tags: isapi, isapi-rewrite

I'm new to ISAPI re-write rules and having some difficulty finding out if I can do the following.

I have ISAPI running on IIS6 and need to do the following.

If have a page where I pass a product ID to:

```
http://www.example.com/downloads/product-page.asp?id=10
```

I want the URL to show the page title in the format:

```
http://www.example.com/downloads/title-of-html-page
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can achieve your scenario by creating mapfiles as described in ISAPI_Rewrite's [FAQ](http://www.helicontech.com/forum/10648-FAQ.html)

Comment: Yeah - The only thing would be that, If I understand correctly, you would have to manually create a new entry in the mapfile for each item in the database. I was wondering if there was a way to do it with a global re-write rule which looked at the title of the page. THanks anyway, I'll try that one first.